# noTone() and tone() are not implemented for the Arduino Due

Tags: arduino, c, piezo-buzzer

As it turns out, [noTone()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/NoTone) and [tone()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Tone) are in the core arduino API, but [seemingly not implemented](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=139683.0) for the [Arduino Due](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoDue).  I was hoping to use `tone()` and `noTone()` to implement the mario death sound found here, but when I add the code and compile it, I get the following errors:

> ```
> trenchRun:154: error: 'tone' was not declared in this scope
> trenchRun:156: error: 'noTone' was not declared in this scope
> ```

In case you're interested, here's an SSCCE, compiled against Arduino 1.5.4 on Mac OS X 10.8:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  tone(1, 12345, 1000);
}
```

> ```
> sketch_oct24a.ino: In function 'void loop()':
> sketch_oct24a:7: error: 'tone' was not declared in this scope
> ```

Since I have an Arduino Due, I am limited in using Arduino 1.5.4.

How do I implement the `tone()` and `noTone()` functions for the Due?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: You have 2 12-bit DACs. Why limit yourself to `tone()`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Could you elaborate? I'm new to hardware programming.

Comment: `tone()` uses a timer to generate a 50% square wave. With a [DAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter) you can create other waveforms, and the Due has more than enough power to do it.

Comment: @MattYoung There are a number of other programming questions on this site; how do you determine whether a hardware programming question is off topic or not?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker When you start talking about APIs, the coding involved has become far enough removed from hardware that it would make more sense to post on SO, and shows little knowledge of the underlying hardware for that matter. Take all of that out and ask about how to generate a tone using a timer/PWM/DAC, and that is dead on topic.